# Problema al escribir ArrayList en un CSV con OpenCSV

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Quiero escribir los datos de cada objeto `Persona` salvado en un `ArrayList` de tipo `Persona` en un file CSV usando la libreria `OpenCSV`, pero la escritura que obtengo en el file csv es incorrecta.

Solo escribe los datos de el primero elemento en la lista y no salta a la siguiente linea.

```
clase Persona:

  public class Persona {

        String Nombre;
        String Apellido;
        String Intereses;
        String Descripcion;

        public Persona(String Nombre,String Apellido,String Intereses,String Descripcion)
        {        
                this.Nombre = Nombre;
                this.Apellido= Apellido;
                this.Intereses = Intereses;
                this.Descripcion = Descripcion;

        }

        public String getNombre(){
            return Nombre;
        }

        public String getApellido(){
            return Apellido;
        }
        public String geIntereses(){
            return Intereses;
        }

        public String getDescripcion(){
            return Descripcion;
        }
    }
```

clase main:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;      
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileWriter;

    import com.opencsv.*;

public class main{

    public static String[] getDatosPersona(Persona persona) {

        String nombre = persona.getNombre();
        String Apellido = persona.getApellido();
        String intereses = persona.geIntereses();
        String descripcion = persona.getDescripcion();

        String []  datos = {nombre,Apellido,intereses,descripcion};

        return datos;

    }

     public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

         ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList();

         Persona persona1 = new Persona("jose","delgado","sus intereses","su descripción");         
         Persona persona2 = new Persona("martin","rosero","sus intereses","su descripción");
         Persona persona3 = new Persona("pedro","cruz","sus intereses","su descripción");


         personas.add(persona1);
         personas.add(persona2);
         personas.add(persona3);



         CSVWriter  csvOutput = new CSVWriter (new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\BryanPC\\Desktop\\otrofile.txt",true));

         for(Persona p:personas){

         csvOutput.writeNext(getDatosPersona(p));


        }
         csvOutput.close();

     }
}
```

output:

```
"jose","delgado","sus intereses","su descripción""jose","delgado","sus intereses","su descripción""jose","delgado","sus intereses","su descripción"
```

output esperado :

```
"jose","delgado","sus intereses","su descripción"
"martin","rosero","sus intereses","su descripción"
"pedro","cruz","sus intereses","su descripción"
```

Comment: Con que herramienta inspeccionas la salida?

Comment: Parece ser un problema de carácter de nueva línea: `\n` or `\r\n`

Comment: Como dice @PaulVargas intenta agregar a esta linea: `String []  datos = {nombre,Apellido,intereses,descripcion};` algo como lo siguiente: `String []  datos = {nombre,Apellido,intereses,descripcion,"\r\n"};`

Comment: El detalle es que se le está triplicando el primer registro, que tal si le quitamos el static al metodo `getDatosPersona` y creas una instancia de tu clase `main` que por cierto tiene muchos defectos de sintaxis :(

Comment: Según leo en la documentación, puedes escribir listas usando el método `csvOutput.writeAll(personas);` sin necesidad de iterarla. Prueba y nos comentas.

Comment: Rosendo con instancia a que te refieres exactamente?

Comment: ya use el metodo writeAll pero sigo teniendo el mismo error , intentare con las secuencias de escape.

Comment: Listo, parece funcionar con usando \r y \n , pero ahora tengo otro problema con las comillas ya que la ultima comilla se "baja" a la siguiente linea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes especificar el carácter de *nueva línea* a utilizar en OpenCSV. Es decir:

```java
Writer writer = FileWriter("C:\\Users\\BryanPC\\Desktop\\otrofile.txt", true);
CSVWriter csvOutput = new CSVWriter(writer, ',', '"', "\r\n");
```